# Como configurar o quaggaJS para boletos do Brasil?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Olá
Estou testando o sandbox do quaggajs e gostaria de saber se alguém já fez configurações especificas para o funcionamento no Brasil.
Tentei rodar o sandbox que é disponibilizado no site, mas ele lê a conta de consumo e não mostra o último digito.
Usei o padrão i2of5 nas configurações.

https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/v1.0.0-beta.1/examples/

Obrigada.

Comment: Oi, Gabriela, tudo bem?
Você conseguiu a resposta?

Comment: @LuisSouza Sim, mas faz muitos anos e sai da empresa que fiz esse projeto.